# Prove that contrapositive rule is equivalent to the rule of double negation

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Many deduction systems I see at various places (for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#In_classical_propositional_calculus_system) includes the following two axioms
$$
a \Rightarrow (b \Rightarrow a),\\
[a \Rightarrow (b \Rightarrow c)]\Rightarrow [(a\Rightarrow b) \Rightarrow ( a \Rightarrow c)].
$$
Now we need a third axiom. I see two versions of the third axiom: $(\neg \neg p) \Rightarrow p$ and $[(\neg p) \Rightarrow (\neg q) ]\Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow p).$

How could we prove using natural deduction that these two versions of "third" axioms are equivalent?

The page in the above link provides one direction of the implication, but I could not find the other direction.

Comment: The deduction system described is much more often referred to as a Hilbert-style system than as a natural deduction system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1): this is the part not provided by Wiki's page above.

1. $¬¬p \to p$ --- Premise
2. $(¬p \to ¬q)$ assumption [a]
3. $q$ --- assumption [b]
4. $¬p$ --- assumption [c]
5. $¬q$ --- from 4) and 2) by $(\to \text E$) (MP)
6. $\bot$ --- contradiction from 3) and 5)
7. $¬¬p$ --- from $(\lnot \text I)$, discharging assumption [c]
8. $p$ --- from 7) and 1) by $(\to \text E$)

> $(q \to p)$ --- from 3) and 8) by $(\to \text I)$, discharging assumption [b].

*Note*: the Natural Deduction derivation above uses the Neg-Intro rule: "if we have derived $\varphi \vdash \bot$, then conclude with $\vdash \lnot \varphi$", i.e. the derivation of a contradiction allow us to negate a premise (see steps 3)-7) above).

With axioms and MP, the derivation requires the following tautology: $(p \to q) \to ((p \to \lnot q) \to \lnot p)$. Using it with $\lnot p$ in place of $p$ will get $\lnot \lnot p$ (step 7) above).

---

A different approach is the following, using a couple of preliminary results:

L1) $p \to p$ --- from (Ax.1) and (Ax.2)

L2) Deduction (meta-)Theorem, proved with (Ax.1), (Ax.2) and L1).

L3) $p \to q, q \to r \vdash p \to r$ (aka: Syllogism), using DT.

Now we have:

1. $\lnot p \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p)$ --- (Ax.1)
2. $(\lnot q \to \lnot p) \to (p \to q)$ --- Contraposition
3. $\lnot p \to (p \to q)$ --- from 1) and 2) by Syll.
4. $\lnot \lnot p \to (\lnot p \to \lnot \lnot \lnot p)$ --- instance of 3)
5. $(\lnot p \to \lnot \lnot \lnot p) \to (\lnot \lnot p \to  p)$ --- Contraposition
6. $\lnot \lnot p \to (\lnot \lnot p \to p)$ --- from 4) and 59 by Syll
7. a suitable instance of (Ax.2) with $\lnot \lnot p \to (\lnot \lnot p \to p)$in place of $[a \to (b \to c)]$
8. $(\lnot \lnot p \to \lnot \lnot p) \to (\lnot \lnot p \to p)$ --- from 6) and 7) by MP

> $\lnot \lnot p \to p$ --- from 8) and L1) by MP.

---

---

Part 2): the proof provided by Wiki's page above uses a sort of trick. Here is the versione for Natural Deduction.

From Contraposition we derive:$(¬¬ \phi \to ¬¬ \psi) \to (\phi \to \psi)$ and we instantiate it with $p$ as $\psi$ and some provable formula (e.g. $p \to p$ or $\top$) as $\phi$, to get:

1. $(¬¬ \top \to ¬¬ p) \to (\top \to p)$.

Then assume 2) $¬¬p$ and from it and $(\to \text I)$ we have:

3. $(¬¬\top \to ¬¬p)$, and
4. $(\top \to p)$ --- from 1) and 3) by $(\to \text E)$.

Now, using 5) $\vdash \top$, we derive:

> $p$ --- from 4) and 5) by $(\to \text E)$.

Comment: Could you do the proof without natural language? Because if you do it this way, it is very hard to see each of the Modus Ponens are used, and very hard to see if the argument is circular. Proving by contradiction itself implicitly assumes some formulae to be true, which need to be explicitly stated. The proof looks circular and I do not know how to use the hint.